# Toggle information pulled from MySQL with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am displaying playlists (from a MySQL db). Playlists contain films. I would like to display all films from a playlist when the playlist is clicked. When the playlist is clicked again I would like the films to fold back.

Moreover, I would like the loading icon to be displayed while the data is being downloaded from the database.

Here is the HTML/PHP for displaying playlists/films:

```
$i = 1;
while($pList = mysqli_fetch_array($playlists))
{   
    echo "<div class=\"plist\" id=\"plist-".$pList["id"]."\">
         Playlist ".$i.": ".$pList["title"]."</div>";
    echo "<div id=\"loaderDiv-".$pList["id"]."\"></div>";
    echo "<div id=\"films-".$pList["id"]."\"></div>";
    $i++;
}
```

and here is the script that I am currently using:

```
$("body").on("click", ".plist", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clickedID = this.id.split("-"); 
    var pID = clickedID[1]; 
    //alert("Playlist clicked: " + pID);
    var myData = 'plistToView='+ pID; 

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "response.php", 
        dataType:"text", 
        data:myData, 
        beforeSend: function(){
            $.get("preloader_JS.html", function (data) {
                $("#loaderDiv-"+pID).append(data);
            });
        },
        success:function(response){
            $("#loaderDiv-"+pID).hide()
            $('#films-'+pID).hide().append(response).slideDown();
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

The films are displayed correctly but I don't know how to hide them back when the playlist is clicked again.

Furthermore, I cannot get the loading icon (`preloader_JS.html`) working on the second playlists after I display information from the first one. (also getting the icon everytime does not seem to make sense - afterall it is the same icon, so I could just get it once and the display it from the same 'source'. Don't really know how to achieve that though.

Any help would be useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little hint from @raam86 I managed to solve my problem on my own.
I stored the information about the current playlist state `($this.data('visible'))`
and the information whether the films from current list have already been downloaded `($this.data('downloaded'))`.
Thanks for help!

here is the code:

```
$("body").on("click", ".plist", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clickedID = this.id.split("-"); 
    var pID = clickedID[1]; 
    //alert("Playlist clicked: " + DbNumberID);
    var myData = 'plistToView='+ pID;

    $this = $(this);

    if($this.data('visible') ){
        $this.data('visible',false);
        $('#films-'+pID).slideUp();
    } else if ($this.data('downloaded') && (!$this.data('visible')))
    {
        $this.data('visible',true);
        $('#films-'+pID).slideDown();
    }
    else 
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "response.php", 
            dataType:"text", 
            data:myData, 
            beforeSend: function(){
                $.get("preloader_JS.html", function (data) {
                    $("#loaderDiv-"+pID).append(data);
                });
            },
            success:function(response){
                $("#loaderDiv-"+pID).hide();
                $this.data('visible',true);
                $this.data('downloaded', true);
                $('#films-'+pID).hide().append(response).slideDown();
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to somehow save state. You can do something like:

```
$("body").on("click", ".plist", function(e) {
 $this = $(this);
if( $this.data('visible') ){
    $this.data('visible',false)
    $this.hide();

success:function(response){
  $("#loaderDiv-"+pID).data('visible',true)
      ....
        }
```